# Erro de sintaxe no Ruby: unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

Ao criar tabelas usei camelcase para criar colunas, só que a usar Ruby on Rails para gerar hash, ao relacionar as duas tabelas aparece menssagem de erro

**Codigo:**

```
@testes = Teste.find_by_sql(
 "
 SELECT * FROM  tabelax
 INNER JOIN tabelay on tabelay."Campoy" =  tabelax."Campox"
 "
)
 render json: @testes
```

**Mensagem de erro:**
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está repetindo as aspas duplas, o Ruby não consegue saber onde termina sua string de fato.

Troque as aspas duplas no começo por simples e resolverá.

```
@testes = Teste.find_by_sql(
 '
 SELECT * FROM  tabelax
 INNER JOIN tabelay on tabelay."Campoy" =  tabelax."Campox"
 '
)
render json: @testes
```

Se você configurar suas classes de forma correta poderá fazer essa query sem SQL, utilizando só o ActiveRecord, como por exemplo:

```
Produto.joins(:vendedor).all
```

Comment: Muito obrigado vnbrs.